# How to extract multiple values in a single regular expression without unwanted values

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract ProjectID and Change Status code value from this paragraph in a single regular expression

```
"projectId:**14152**,changeOrderCount:0,parentProjectName:"test_new_estimate",hidden:false,teamLeaderName:null,proposalPrice:null,dateRequiredWdd:null,contractorName:null,description:"test1",shopState:"AZ",openingHeightPlus:null,engineerName:null,projectEstimatorEmail:null,bypassDoorOverlap:"0",shopCountry:"US",finishHdwBy:null,specificationsDated:null,jobsiteCountry:null,teamLeader3LastName:null,hardwareOnly:false,installationRate:40.00,bidStatus:-581001,jobSiteSuper:null,jobsiteEmail:null,shopCity:"Phoenix",changeStatusCode:"**Started**","
```

I tried using this expression

```
",projectId:(.*?),|changeStatusCode:"(.*?)""
```

but I am getting result 14152null

I need only these two values

Expected values: 14152Started

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use regular expressions you can amend your to look like:

```
"projectId:(\d+),|changeStatusCode:"(.+?)"
```

however [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence I would rather recommend using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) instead

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is not a proper JSON response it is GWT framework response so we cant use JSON Extractor. For that only I am trying to get both values. I used your regular expression but still I am getting results as "14152null". Can you please help me in any other way .